# Experiencing slow booting times in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've taken over a project and have noticed their booting times are outrageous average out 2-3 seconds, but have seen them hit as far as 9-10 second using Laravel Debugbar.

Now, trying to determine the source of this I've created a new application under the same server and using the same MySQL server. I've even got the blades for a basic page recreated and the difference is huge. Booting is down to maybe 3.4 to 5.6ms on average, all while using the same database, same server and same blade templating (at least for an example).

Now my question is, based on these factors, is there something I can do to try and locate where the real issue is for booting time delays in the old one (mind you, it is regularly updated to the most stable version of Laravel, so it's not old in the since of Laravel 4.1 or anything)? I'd hate to have to rebuild the entire thing, but would absolutely prefer that over these slow times for a project that I wouldn't consider simple but definitely not complex either.

I was hoping Laravel Debugbar might give me the hint I needed but the delays definitely don't have anything to do with the database as far as I'm concerned...

I should mention that I’ve gone through the regular caching artisan commands such as route, view, `config:cache`, etc. Session caching and general caching is handled through Redis.

Comment: You want to profile your laravel app. Google it as i see multiple posts on the subject

Answer (score 7):

I would check what service providers and middlewares are executed during lifecycle of a request. But I give you a list of what I would do to debug this stuff.

- Check `'providers'` in `config/app.php` and disable everything under the "Application Service Providers" section.
- Check middlewares configuration under `app/Kernel.php` and look if there is something suspicious.
- Create a new `/test` route with a new controller, with no middleware and check access time for that route. If it's fast, then there is some bloatware executing for other routes.
- Check responses of artisan commands. When an artisan command is executed, all service providers are loaded (but not middlewares). A simple `php artisan` that will show all the commands should be instant
- Enable query log in MySQL and check all the queries coming for a simple request.

Comment: I’m going to go through your suggestions one at a time and let you know. Though I tried your suggestion about php artisan first. I found a 8-10 second lag in the return. Whereas on the test site, which is just a sibling folder, it came back instantaneous (or near enough so).

Comment: The test route and controller that you suggested has the same access time.

Comment: Disabling the Application Service Providers has no noticeable effect.

Comment: The middlewares currently enables are the defaults set and there’s nothing that looks off about them.

Comment: Copy `app` folder from the slow app to the new app, and test response time.

If response times are fast do the same with other directories, one by one. 

You said you are using same MySQL server for both app, have you tested using the same database?

Comment: BTW I am just throwing suggestions to help out, probably a solution can be found profiling your PHP code and see where the slowness happens